# "Doing something" when a new page is created

Tags: page-numbering, includegraphics

I have custom page number images that I want to place at the bottom of a given page to represent its page number.

The MWE does just this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, margin=15mm, bindingoffset=0mm, heightrounded}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand{\putpagenumberimage}{}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\newcounter{lastpagenumber} % \pageref{LastPage} = 2\hbox{}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \addtocounter{lastpagenumber}{\pageref{LastPage}}
    \newcommand{\pagenumberimage}{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{97.5mm}, \LenToUnit{3.75mm}){\includegraphics[width=21.75mm, height=7.5mm]{page-\thepage-of-\thelastpagenumber.eps}}%
    }
}


\begin{document}

First page\\
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\pagenumberimage}
\newpage

Second page\\
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\pagenumberimage}

\end{document}
```

However, I want `\AddToShipoutPicture*{\pagenumberimage}` to be called whenever LaTeX generates a new page (**i.e. not only when I manually call `\newpage`**).

Is there a way to achieve this please?

Comment: Couldn't you simply clear the default footer of the document and place your custom image in there instead?

Comment: @Raven Could you show me how, please? Also, the image isn't fixed -- it changes depending on the page number. Thanks,

Comment: Do I assume correctly that you have a separate image file for each and every page that is going to be created? And you simply want a system that picks the right one based on which page you're on?

Comment: You could really wrap this into a `\pagestyle`. That would still be dynamic.

Comment: @Raven Exactly. The line `\includegraphics[width=21.75mm, height=7.5mm]{page-\thepage-of-\thelastpagenumber.eps}` picks the correct page, So I just want the `\AddToShipoutPicture*{\pagenumberimage}` to be called every time a new page is created. Thanks.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks. How would I go about that, please?

Comment: Have a look at packages like `fancyhdr`. They provide means to create a new page style or alter the existing ones. Then simply put this as footer content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % fancyhdr package
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyfoot{\AddToShipoutPicture*{\pagenumberimage}}

    first page

    \newpage

    second test
\end{document}
```

This (along with your code) should do the trick. I can't test it properly though as I don't have the images on my machine.

A little side note: If I was you I'd go with procedural generated images via `tikz` (or similar) so that it would be more universally usable. And when using `\tikzexternalize` the compile-time should only be influenced if a new page is being added.